# Azure Powershell script creation of a GLOBAL documentdb using a json template

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-powershell

i can create a powershell script that call New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment and uses a json template to create a documentdb in azure.   I would like to create a GLOBAL documentdb that is a new feature for documentdbs.   I haven't seen how to do this.

the original json template snippet creates a document db works FINE!

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts",      
  "name": "[variables('databaseAccountName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "documentDbAccount"
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "[variables('databaseAccountName')]",
    "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard"
  }
},
```

but it doesn't create it with a GLOBAL 'kind'. 
i've seen this mentioned somewhere

"kind": "GlobalDocumentDB"

so i tried adding that into the json after type,

```
 {
  "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts",
  "kind": "GlobalDocumentDB",
  "name": "[variables('databaseAccountName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "documentDbAccount"
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "[variables('databaseAccountName')]",
    "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard"
  }
},
```

but this fails.   so obviously not the way to create a GLOBAL Documentdb.

Anyone know what is needed??? tx much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for removing the answer, but there is a more complete set of documentation coming very soon, then we will get an answer out here.